# Verification of proof that the left distributive property holds on a field of quotients, F

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

Here's my proof.  I would like to know whether it is right or wrong and if the latter where it needs to be corrected:

(a,b)=[(a,b)][(cf+ed,df)]=[(acf+aed,bdf)].
We want to show its equivalence to:
[(ac,bd)]+[(ae,bf)]=[(acbf+abde,$b^2$df)]

By the equivalence relation
[(acf+aed,bdf)]~[(acbf+abde,$b^2$df)] 
means the following:

(acf+aed)$b^2$df=(bdf)(acbf+abde)=acf$b^2$df+aed$b^2$df=bdfacbf+bdfabde

Since a field is commutative
ac$f^2$$b^2$d+ae$d^2b^2$f=ac$f^2b^2$d+ae$d^2b^2$f

Please let me know what can be changed.